# inserting a C# line to a file with powershell and it doesnt treat it like text even with commas

Tags: c#, json, powershell

im writing a script that takes a request from the user and makes a file and writes a line of code in it according to the user choice.
it works greate when i write something like "hello" but when i take the code line and put it between commas it doesnt treat it like text. if someone know what the problem is or how can i solve this it would be great, thanks for the help!

this is how it looks like when i write hello:

```
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello"
```

and this is when i put the code instead:

```
New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "{"sys_ver":"01.01.01.02","RED":[],"RED_VA":[],"BLACK":[{"type":"6","type_descr":"DSP file","tar_name":"dsp.tar.gz","image_name":"dsp.z","CRC":"1234567","version":"01.01.01.02","metadata":"62056"}
],"BLACK_VA":[]
}
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```
New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value @"
"{"sys_ver":"01.01.01.02","RED":[],"RED_VA":[],"BLACK":[{"type":"6","type_descr":"DSP file","tar_name":"dsp.tar.gz","image_name":"dsp.z","CRC":"1234567","version":"01.01.01.02","metadata":"62056"}
],"BLACK_VA":[]
}"
"@
```